# Is this a typo/error in the Galois/Counter mode specification or have I misunderstood?

Tags: aes, gcm, aes-gcm

I've been reading the following document describing Galois Counter Mode:
[The Galois/Counter Mode of Operation](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.694.695&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

On page 7 of the document, the following diagram describes the `GHASH` function used to authenticate data.  `GHASH` is defined as `GHASH(H, A, C)` where H is a 128-bit unsigned integer and A and C are two bit strings representing the authenticated data $A$ and ciphertext $C$.  $m$ and $n$ are used to represent the number of 128 bit blocks of data in $A$ and $C$ respectively.

[image: GCM GHASH]

Equation 4 and 5 look incorrect to me.  Is $C_i$ correct on line 4?  Won't $i$ already be larger than $m$ and thus this won't include the correct blocks of $C$?  Shouldn't this be $C_{i-m}$?

And the fifth equation, is this meant to be $C^{*}_{n}$ and not $C^{*}_{m}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Examining the document, it seems that you are correct on both equations. Thus

$$
C_i ~~\textrm{should be}~~C_{i-m},
$$

and

$$
C_m^* ~~\textrm{should be }C_n^*.
$$